# get contents from database without refreshing page complete script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with this code
I have a php code that get contents from DB
I want to load this contents in a div with "link" class without refreshing page

this code

```php
<?
include('config.php');
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `database` order by desc limit 1");
while($rw = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    $id = $rw['id'];


$title = $rw['title'];

?>

<div class="link">
<?
echo $title;
?>

</div>
```

and one of members gives this code to me 
and told me 
"Script for your web page:"

```js
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and "then you need to create a getData.php file that does your data execution in your question and barfs it up for the ajax call to dump in the txtData control (or wherever else you want the data to go.)"

Now my problem is:
I know only css and php and don't understand the above code.

Please give me a complete code and script

Comment: I think the one who gave you the codes has already explain it clear enough. It's some answer you'll get if you don't paste the code above.

Comment: _"please give me a complete code"_ Nope, not gonna happen, SO isn't a free coding service, if you want the coding to be done for you, you'll have to hire a freelancer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the AJAX code in a function, and call the function in your HTML page when you want to load the data from the PHP into the `div` tag with *link* class:

```
function loadData(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Quick explanation...

`var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` creates a javascript *object* to perform the AJAX data transactions

`xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =...` tells the webpage which function to execute when the `onreadystatechange` event happens

`xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php?q=" + str, true);` this set all the information to be sent to the *getData.php* in the background via the *GET* method

`xmlhttp.send();` performs the request

`xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200` is the state of the `xmlhttp` object when a response has been received from the PHP page

`document.getElementById("txtData").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` gets the response data available in `xmlhttp.responseText` and sets the data in element with id `txtData`

I hope this helps :)